# Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DT\Test$'

Tags: sql-server

I get the following error when trying to run a web app using windows auth.

> Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'DT\Test$'.

When I run

```
USE Test
GO
SELECT USER_ID('DT\Test$')
```

it returns `7`

So not sure what the issue is

Here is my connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="TestModel" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=&quot;mydb.com, 1433&quot;;initial catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I should also add that the webapp works fine when I am logged in as my domain account in visual studio, just not when deployed to the production server

Comment: What does your `web.config` connection string look like?

Comment: @WEI_DBA add it to question

Answer (score 0):

Solved: changed app pool identity to LocalSystem